# How does Google Chrome Devtools Network get iframe fetch event?

Tags: javascript, iframe, request, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a website with an iframe embeded and I've been looking at Google Chrome Devtools' Network tab. When I look at it I found out that it shows 3rd party fetch requests. How does it achieve this? Can I get the same result in Javascript?

Comment: DevTools is a part of the browser so it can access anything. Sites can't access cross-origin iframes.

Answer (score -1):

in the new versions of chromium that feature is disabled, please use <92 versions,  it will captue all requests including iframe requests